# Meaning of 'get the girls onto the club's floor'

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the club concert...

> Mary is surprised – yet not surprised – when her attempts to **get the
> girls onto the club's floor** are ineffective... and unnecessary.

What is "get the girls onto the club's floor" mean?

Comment: It is hard to see how her efforts could be simultaneously ineffective and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The "floor" of the club refers to the dance floor, ie the bit of the club where the dancing happens. Mary seems to be trying to get "the girls" to go and dance.

Comment: There are other meanings for 'get a girl on the floor' which are almost certainly not intended.